# SQLite JDBC Class Not Found Exception

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc, ivy

I've been trying to make use of the SQLite jdbc class from Xerial. Every time I try to run what I have, it fails, giving me the following error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.sqlite.Driver
```

I'm using Ivy, and have the following in my `ivy.xml` file.

```
<dependency org="org.xerial" name="sqlite-jdbc" rev="3.7.2"/>
```

This includes the sqlite-jdbc-3.7.2.jar file in my class path. I've also tried manually adding it, to no avail.

The command that runs this also contains the jar on the command line:

```
java -cp ... sqlite-jdbc-3.7.2.jar ...
```

I still get the class not found exception on the following line:

```
Class.forName("org.sqlite.Driver");
```

I've tried searching around for this particular issue, but it seems most of the time it's resolved simply by including the jar in the class path, which shouldn't be the issue here, as Eclipse lists the jar in the class path.

Comment: Did you unzip the JAR and see if the Driver class is present ?

Answer (score 4):

Can you confirm that the jar version `sqlite-jdbc-3.7.2` has class `org.sqlite.Driver`?

You can check it by unzipping the jar file and check if unzippied folder has directory structure `org\sqlite\Driver.class`?

I think the sqlLite Driver name is `org.sqlite.JDBC` and `not org.sqlite.Driver` . [Source](https://bitbucket.org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc).

Comment: And there it is. a bit of habbit (using the posgresql driver) and lysdexia leads to an easy to solve problem. Just one of those things I needed another set of eyes on. Thanks!